# How to apply routes in electron?

Tags: node.js, routes, electron

I am displaying dynamic data (as items) from the server, in the client. When the user click on an item, he will be directed to the item's view page using its `_id`.

For example in `MeteorJS`, the router is created as below:

```
Router.route('/item/:_id', function(){
  Session.set("itemId", this.params._id);
  this.render("navbar", {to:"navbar"});
  this.render("itemDetailsB", {to:"main"});
});
```

where `:_id` will equal to the item's id (that has been clicked)

How can I retrieve the `_id` in electron?